# Only one section in Indexed Table

Tags: ios, tableview, indexed

I want to make an indexed table.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
self.heroes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Aaaa",@"Abbbbb",@"Bbbbb",@"Nnnnn",@"Pppp",@"Xxxx",@"Zzzzz", nil];
}



- (NSArray *)sortedArrayFromArray:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector{
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex: section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

But when the app starts, there is only one index named "A". What am i doing wrong?

(Array displays correctly)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have this method? - (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView

Comment: here there is detailed example http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't implemented some methods it seems

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles]count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_heroes count]/*do according to your need*/;
}
```

in this case `numberOfRowsInSection` should implement very carefully that actually tells you how much row should be under one section (say "A" or "B" etc).

than it may work for you.